# How to append a counter to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

need to append a counter few spaces way from the text " list of items".

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peppygo/nat3ceb0/1/)

```
<div class="itemshead" style="margin-top:4px;"><div class="items">List of Items</div></div>
var count = 00;
  counter = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds ");
    count++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/n5raoqjx/](http://jsfiddle.net/n5raoqjx/)

Comment: just use `<div class="itemshead" style="margin-top:4px;"><div class="items">List of Items <p class="countdown"></p></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a `p` tag with the class `.counter`. Add this element.

I would suggest using a `span` rather that a `p` if you want it to appear inline with your current text...

```js
var count = 00;
counter = setInterval(function(){
  $(".countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
  count++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemshead" style="margin-top:4px;"><div class="items">List of Items <span class="countdown"></span></div></div>
```